# Visual Studio Code + Spring Boot Project change spring.properties.additional-location etc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

Recently i decided to `pass from Eclipse to VS Code` , everything is running smoothly for Javascript development but for `Spring Boot` applications i don't know how to configure them here .

Except of the `application.properties` file i have one more extra `local.properties` which i use to run locally the Spring Boot Application .

I see there is a `launch.json` file :

```
{
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - fmApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.application.zz.app.fmApplication",
            "projectName": "file-manager"
        }
    ]
}
```

In Eclipse i am adding additional configuration to run my Spring Boot Application like shown below :

[image]

How can i do that is Vs Code :) ?

[Here is the issue on Vs Code Github Page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/451)

Comment: This will be a bit off-topic, but I'd suggest you trying IntelliJ IDEA, I used it for spring-boot development along with Angular and I wouldn't change it!

Comment: @Pijotrek Yes IntelliJ IDEA is superior but i don't like it , i prefer VS Code for many reasons . For lightweight , one for all and many other .... of course the free too.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, Java code needs to be compiled so it wont work out of the box with visual studio code since it's just a glorified text editor.

There are however multiple tools to accommodate for this, and the folks at VS code 
have a nice guide for setting you up - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot

---

**Solution :**

So you have an `application.properties` file and locally you have a `application-local.properties`(**attention , you must name your local properties like that**).

Then in your launch.json you add it to your program parameters :

`"args": "--spring.profiles.active=local"`

So your `launch.json` file will look like this for example :

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - fmApplication",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "com.intralot.l10.app.fmApplication",
      "projectName": "file-manager",
      "args": "--spring.profiles.active=local"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Of course i have added all the needed plugins before i post this question :) Ivan i need to configure Java Spring Boot in order to add my local.properties which overrides application.properties file . Do you know how i can do that `Ivan` ?

Comment: Oh, to do that, you should name the file application-local.properties and add to launch.json - "args": "--spring.profiles.active=local",

Comment: I will test this solution today :) And if it works i want you to add it in your answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Ivan you are awesome! Please add it to your answer!

Comment: `Ivan` :) mmmm guess who . Do you know if i can evaluate Java Code with vs code also :) ?

Comment: Evaluate as in build or debug? Or get IntelliSense support? Any of those things are  achievable through vs code extensions. I am not really that vs code savvy as I use IntJ myself :)

Comment: Ivan i want to evaluate on Debug mode :) Is this possible on build mode :) ?

Comment: Something like this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging

Comment: Yes thank you :) . One more think Ivan do you believe Vs code is going to dominate the Java Market also like IntelliJ now ?

Comment: It's on the rise for sure but hard to say if it will dominate. IntJ is deeply rooted and won't move soon, and most students are accustomed to using eclipse as that's what they use on courses. VS code unlike the other two requires a bit more work to set up with all the extensions and that's something that's bound to hold it back, even with all the superb guides they put out. But if you are willing to put in the work, it can be just as potent as the other options, and if you prefer it, go for it.

Comment: not working. I'm trying to do this for a kotlin project and the profile doesn't get activated.

Comment: I had to step back a little further and create a launch.json file, I followed the instructions here, and selected "Java".

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: Why the configs of the `application-local.properties` does not combined with `application.properties`?

Comment: you don't have to name it "application-local.properties" /  "something-somethingelse.properties" also working if you set the args to "--spring.profiles.active=somethingelse"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Spring Boot Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard) you can right click on the application and select the profiles you want to be activated for executing the application. Note that the list of profiles is listed using the application properties/yaml files. So keep even an empty file in the resources folder for the profile to be listed.

Comment: it's much easier